# Are string constants in Groovy interned like they are in Java?

Tags: groovy

I'm creating large data structures of lists and maps with strings as keys in those maps. The same keys are used over and over again thousands of times. If these strings are not interned my code will consume a lot of memory with just repetitions of the same text.

To create these structures I'm using the map literal syntax, and it's specifically the constants there I'm curious about.

```
[
  name: "text",
  children: something.collect { [name: it.name, city: it.city] }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, regarding your question strings behave in groovy just the way they do in java. You can easily test this by opening a groovyConsole:

```
def a = "test"
def b = "test"

assert a.is(b) // asserts true
```

Since == is used to test object equality, you have to use is() to test if your variables reference the same object.

Comment: And to answer the other half of the question; yes, the map keys when using the syntax [key: value] are regarded as string constants. So `assert [name:'a'].keySet().first().is('name')` also validates to true. If you resolve the keys at runtime, e.g. by reading from a file, the instances will not be the same.